# Tsconfig paths glob wildcard, why does this not work?

Tags: typescript, import, path, config, wildcard

While setting up some tests that imported an external type, the IDE gave me errors that it could not find the required module. Originally, the `tsconfig.json` was set up as:

*Import*:

```
import type {type} from "@src/types/type";
```

*Path:*

```
"paths": {
      "@src/*": ["./src/**/*"}
}
```

I looked up tsconfig docs and found what it was supposed to be: a single glob wildcard that has to match the key (which makes sense):

```
"paths": {
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"}
}
```

This ultimately fixed the issue and I found out that the paths and key are both used together. After finding this out, I tried implementing a double glob and a single glob:

```
"paths": {
      "@src/**/*": ["./src/**/*"}
}
```

This approach doesn't work and the errors still appear and I don't understand why. Especially as the include tag uses this:

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
```

Would anyone be able to describe what I'm missing?

I tried looking up docs for explanations and Stack Overflow to see if anyone had a similar experience. From what I found from the docs and other sources, my suggestion to have the double glob and a single glob makes sense - but doesn't work in practice.